# Expand row passed as a prop has no effect

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-bootstrap-table

I am using react-bootstrap-table2, along with typescript. I have a wrapper component called `<Table>` which ultimately renders `<BootstrapTable>` component.

When I pass `expandRow` prop to my wrapper component, which passes it on to the underlying `<BootstrapTable>` component, it simply makes no effect, when row is clicked. And I see this error in the console.

> Uncaught Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child
>   (found: object with keys {status, type, comments}). If you meant to
>   render a collection of children, use an array instead.

```
// does not work
// when passed as prop
const expandRow = {
    renderer: (row: any) => (<h3>Expanded content</h3>)
}
//Wrapper component
<Table expandRow={expandRow} />
...
export class Table extends React.Component {
    render(){
         ....
        return (
             <BootstrapTable ... expandRow={this.props.expandRow} />
        )
    }

...
}
```

But instead, when I define `expandRow` inside the wrapper component and pass as prop to the `<BootstrapTable>`, it works.

```
// works
<Table />
...
export class Table extends React.Component {
   render(){
       const expandRow = {
          renderer: (row: any) => (<h3>Expanded content</h3>)
       }
       return (
          <BootstrapTable ... expandRow={expandRow} />
       )
   }
}
```

What is happening wrong here?

Comment: can you show us the console.log(this.props.expandRow) output for the first example?

Comment: I have added it. See in yellow in the question. Can't share screenshot.

Comment: That is the error message of the render fucntion but not the console.log(this.props.expandRow).

Comment: I tried both the cases you mentioned, it worked for me every time. Sandbox link - https://codesandbox.io/embed/react-boot-table-expand-row-592ct